# Difference between ISQL and DBISQL

Tags: database, data-warehouse, sap-iq

I am reading SYBASE documentation and I don't understand what is the difference between `dbisql` and `isql`. Are the interchangeable, do they have the same functionality, when to use one than the other?

Answer (score 1):

Isql doesnt let you create user-defined database options. If you need to add your own database options, use the dbisql Interactive SQL utility instead.

I dont know if there are more differences, but if they exist, it is probably only in some specific functions that better work with dbisql than isql.